# Getting error with PyAudio even though I have the latest PyAudio

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following python program but i am getting some errors.  The program is intended to convert livespeech to text and it is using an acoustic model which I have trained using CMUSphinx.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import speech_recognition as sr
from pocketsphinx import AudioFile

hmm = '/home/ridwan/sphinx/other2/model_parameters/other2.ci_cont' #folder of the acoustic model
lm = '/home/ridwan/sphinx/other2/etc/other2.lm.DMP' #language model
dict = '/home/ridwan/sphinx/other2/etc/other2.dic' #the phonetic dictionary

#model_path = get_model_path()
#data_path = get_data_path()

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...")  
    # listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy level  
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)  
        print("Say something!")  
        audio = r.listen(source)

config = {
    'verbose': False,
    'audio_file': audio,
    'buffer_size': 2048,
    'no_search': False,
    'full_utt': False,
    'hmm': hmm,
    'lm': lm,
    'dict': dict
}

audio = AudioFile(**config)
for phrase in audio:
    print(phrase)
```

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 15, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 113, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("PyAudio 0.2.11 or later is required (found version {})".format(pyaudio.__version__))
AttributeError: PyAudio 0.2.11 or later is required (found version 0.2.10)
```

But I have already installed PyAudio 0.2.11. When I do `pip install pyaudio`, I get the following:

> Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.2.11)

Comment: try `pip install pyaudio --upgrade`

Comment: Already did that.

Comment: Your error message indicates that it is using a pyaudio installed in python 2.7, but your message at the bottom is referencing a pyaudio in python3. Try using python3 explicitly to call the program

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: in your shebang at the top, change it to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. If you execute the command with `python myprogram.py` use `python3 myprogram.py` instead. Both of these should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message indicates that it is using a pyaudio installed in python2.7, but your error message at the bottom is referencing a pyaudio in python3. Try using python3 explicitly to call the program. You can ensure that by doing the following:

1. Change the shebang line at the top of the file to tell the shell what to use to execute the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

1. invoke it directly on the command line when calling the script:

```
$ python3 myscript.py
```

These will fix your issue and use the correct version of python to run the program.